# Embedded Jetty 8 and configuration of JNDI MySQL connection pool with no XML

Tags: java, maven, jndi, connection-pooling, embedded-jetty

I have been searching a good while now, and I am not able to find any good tutorials or answers to this question.

In this project there are only one XML-file, pom.xml, the server is an embedded Jetty 8, with a programmatically defined ServletContextHandler that handles all the incoming requests. My point is, no WebAppContext or WAR-file(as it seems like all tutorials expect a WEB-INF, WebAppContext, web.xml, jetty-env.xml or WAR file).

I simply want to add a JNDI-datasource for pooling sql-connections programmatically in Java. Are there anyone that could point me to a good tutorial, or give some tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chosen an `embedded-jetty` with its special `ServletContextHandler` without a complete web container (that's not meant to be criticism, just the path you have followed so far).

If this is your target environment as well, why do you need JNDI on top of this? Something has to provide the JNDI implementation. I would just add a connection pool like BoneCP, C3PO etc. and use it without JNDI.

On the other hand, if your target environment requires you to use a connection pool, you can always add your own method on top of both providers:

Pseudo code:

```
public class MyConnectionFactory

// To be replaced with a property lookup etc.
private boolean development = true;

public Connection getConnection(String jndiName)
  if (development)
    // get connection from BoneCP etc. (ignore jndiName)
  else {
    // lookup data source using JNDI, then get connection
```

and then in your source always use this method.